# python curses textbox widget

Tags: python, curses

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import curses
import curses.textpad as textpad

try:
    mainwindow = curses.initscr()
    textpad.Textbox(mainwindow).edit()
finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

the problem is that I type one character,but two characters display on screen.

Comment: I must say that the title of this question is rather funny if you initially misinterpret 'curses' as a verb rather than the name of a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echoing is on by default. You need to call `noecho` for deactivating it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses
import curses.textpad as textpad

try:
    mainwindow = curses.initscr()
    # Some curses-friendly terminal settings
    curses.cbreak(); mainwindow.keypad(1); curses.noecho()
    textpad.Textbox(mainwindow).edit()
finally:
    # Reverse curses-friendly terminal settings
    curses.nocbreak(); mainwindow.keypad(0); curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
```

(the script has been tested on Python 2.7). I suggest you to have a look to the [curses programming page](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`curses.noecho()`](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html#starting-and-ending-a-curses-application) :

```
import curses
import curses.textpad as textpad

try:
    mainwindow = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    textpad.Textbox(mainwindow).edit()
finally:
    curses.endwin()
```